# Repeated use of Woodbury formula

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse

I want to calculate the $x$ dependency of $\left(I + A \Lambda (x) A^{T}+B\Omega(x)B^{T}\right)^{-1}$ explicitly, where $I$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Here $\Lambda (x) $ and $\Omega(x)$ are diagonal $m\times m$ matrices with entries $\frac{1}{x-\lambda_i}$, $\frac{1}{x-\omega_i}$, $i=1,...,m$

Assuming I just want to solve $\left(I + A \Lambda (x) A^{T}\right)^{-1}$ I can use the Woodbury formula to get
$I - A (\Lambda^{-1} (x)-A^T A)^{-1} A^T
= I - A (x - diag\left(\lambda_i\right) -A^T A)^{-1} A^T$

Thus I can calculate the eigenvalues and vectors of $diag\left(\lambda_i\right) +A^T A$ and then have the explicit $x$ dependency when I insert the eigendecomposition for this expression.

The original expression however prohibits this straightforward approach and I'm stuck. Using Woodbury formula twice doesn't seem to help here in my opinion. Any hints or ideas?

Comment: Are $\Lambda(x),\Omega(x)$ each proportional to the identity matrix?

Comment: I edited the post, should be clearer now.

Comment: Probably the simplest statement is just that $\Lambda(x)=(xI_m-\lambda)^{-1}$ where $\lambda=\text{diag}(\lambda_i)$ (and similarly for $\Omega(x)$.

Comment: One inconsistency: You state that the diagonal matrices are $m\times m$, but you've already given that $I$ is $n\times n$.

Comment: Yes, this works if $A$ is $n \times m$. This is supported by the Woodbury formula.

Comment: Fair enough. It's probably better to point that out, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a found a good workaround.

Just rewrite the expression in the beginning

$\left(I_n + A \Lambda (x) A^{T}+B\Omega(x)B^{T}\right)^{-1} = \left( I_n + \begin{pmatrix}
        I_n & I_n  \\
        \end{pmatrix}   \begin{pmatrix}
        A & 0  \\
        0 & B \\
        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        \Lambda(x) & 0  \\
        0 & \Omega(x) \\
        \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
        A^T & 0  \\
        0 & B^T \\
        \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
        I_n   \\
        I_n\\
        \end{pmatrix}  \right)^{-1}$

From here one can proceed as was done above, the matrix to diagonalze just becomes double in size.

Comment: This is a nice approach via block matrices---well done! I'm curious what the Woodbury formula gives in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The following is intended to supplement the opening post by showing what happens when the Woodbury matrix identity is applied twice. I had initially hope to make an answer out of it, but this proved unsuccessful. Perhaps someone else can find use in it...

---

For clarity's sake, we recall that the Woodbury matrix identity states that $$(A+UCV)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)^{-1}VA^{-1}$$
where $A,C,U,V$ are matrices of appropriate size.

In the problem at hand, we have $M(x)=(I_n+A \Lambda(x) A^T+B\Omega(x) B^T)^{-1}$ where $\Lambda(x)=(xI_m-\lambda)^{-1}$, $\Omega(x)=(xI_m-\omega)^{-1}$ and $\lambda=\text{diag}(\lambda_i),\omega=\text{diag}(\omega_i)$. Ignoring $\Omega(x)$ for now, from the Woodbury matrix formula we deduce
\begin{align}
M_0(x)\equiv (I_n+A\Lambda(x)A^T)^{-1} 
&= I_n - A(\Lambda(x)^{-1}+A^T A)^{-1}A^T\\
&=I_n - A(xI_m-\lambda+A^T A)^{-1}A^T
\end{align}
as in the OP. If we now take $I_n+A\Lambda(x)A^T$ as "$A$" in the Woodbury formula, we obtain
\begin{align}
M(x)
&=M_0(x)-M_0(x)B(\Omega(x)^{-1}+B^T M_0(x) B)^{-1}B^TM_0(x)\\
&=M_0(x)-M_0(x)B(xI_m-\omega+B^T M_0(x) B)^{-1} B^T M_0(x)
\end{align}
which, alas, hardly seems more tractable than the initial formula.

Comment: Yeah just repeating woodbury here doesn't seem to have any value I think. Also you missed an $A^{-1}$ in the first row of $M(x)$ between $B^T$ and $B$. And that is the problematic term, because it has a $x$ dependency then.

Comment: Agreed. I've fixed the error for sake of completeness. @J.Goe